# how to reduce number of events generated

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, events

I'm calling a soap service that given an id returns an entity. Each request only accepts one id, so I need to call the web service many times to load all the entities (10k).

I have multiple threads making the requests, and they all insert the entities in a concurrent dictionary. The entire process takes several minutes, but I'd like to pass back the results to the caller from time to time, let's say every 100 entities received.

I know I can use events buy I don't want to fire an event for each entity received. Also, I don't want to check at every entity received if a counter reaches 100, I'm afraid about performance as the counter would have to be synchronized.

What would you suggest? Should I use events? Anything else?

Comment: You can't change the SOAP service to accept a range of IDs?

Comment: No, it is not controlled by me and it is practically impossible to change that in a time effective way

Comment: I'd be very wary of using multithreading in this context too. Quoting the old joke... A programmer had a problem. He thought to himself, "I know, I'll solve it with threads!". has Now problems. two he

Comment: No choice, using only one thread makes the process too long (1+ hour). With multithreading I managed to have the result in less than 10 mins

Comment: You are worried that synchronized counter over 10K would cause performance issues?  Did you try it?

Comment: Honestly I haven't tried it.. Part of my question was (maybe not too clear) if it could cause performance issues

Comment: What _have_ you tried? Where is your code? What does your code do? How is that different from what you want it to do?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the capacity to "batch" your threads, then this could work.

Use `Task` instead of a `Thread`, then batch the creation of these. Finally, utilize [`Task.WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
// Construct started tasks
Task[] tasks = new Task[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    //action is your method as a delegate
    tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(action);
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
FireHundredComplete(); //Invoke your event
```

Now, you will need to run each of *those* on a separate thread/Task, as `Task.WaitAll` will block ( and its not async, so you can't `await` it).

You also will have lots of these events firing at seemingly random intervals, since each set of tasks could finish at any time. Synchronization could easily still be an issue.

Comment: I'm actually already using tasks.. However in my case this would introduce even more delay. I tested a similar approach and its actually much faster to request as many entities as possible (the service could return null, in which case the request should be made again, possibly even more than once). Can't wait for the first 100 to finish, I need to request as many as possible..

Comment: @user1448276 Right, which is why I suggested creating a whole bunch of these "batches" in *parallel*. You still have potential synchronization issues (as I've noted) but it gets around the counter issue.

Comment: I see. Also, when the event is fired, the associated method would be executed in the wrong thread. Are events thread safe? I mean it I fire 200 events in short time from different threads, is there a chance I lose any?

Comment: @user1448276 You certainly wouldn't *lose* any, they would all execute. As you say, they all execute separately (and UI updates would need to marshal to the UI thread). The issue isn't losing any, but synchronization issues (such as a total count). You were always going to have that if you want to fire events as you go along though.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, I don't want to check at every entity received if a counter reaches 100, I'm afraid about performance as the counter would have to be synchronized.

Don't be; incrementing a counter in a synchronized block is *insanely* quick; locks are actually pretty cheap, so a simple implementation could be simply:

```
bool raiseEvent;
lock(sharedLock) {
    raiseEvent = (++counter % EventFrequency) == 0;
}
if(raiseEvent) {...}
```

However, you can do it *even more efficiently* with an interlock:

```
if((Interlocked.Increment(ref counter) % EventFrequency) == 0)
{ ... }
```

However! It seems to mean that the real "performance" issue here is making a huge number of web-service calls. I strongly recommend making that more batch-esque. That doesn't necessary mean "everything in one batch", but 100 batches of 100 items will perform much better than 10,000 individual calls (and will often also perform better than 1 batch of 10,000 items).